# Please move over Blog posts from blog.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, blog

I read an article last year on "Speeding up Stack Exchange" that talked in depth about the 'multi-tenancy' nature of the (then) Stack Exchange 1.0 sites.  I tried finding that link again today, and instead found the [Twitter Trackbacks](http://topsy.com/blog.stackexchange.com/post/459188139/speeding-up-stackexchange) for it. The article itself brings up a 404, and it leads me to believe that the posts from blog.stackexchange.com weren't ported over, or if they were, there aren't any redirects issued for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view the old blog at http://stackexchange.tumblr.com/.  I think the actual post you want is here: http://stackexchange.tumblr.com/post/459188139/speeding-up-stackexchange

We only migrated over the last few posts to [blog.stackexchange.com](http://blog.stackexchange.com), since they were the only ones actually still relevant in the new Stack Exchange.

Comment: That link gives 404 Not found - do you still have a copy?